# Spring batch generating reports

Tags: spring-batch

I would like to generate a summary report at the end of my batch execution.

For ex: I have an ItemProcessor which receives accountId.

`for every accountId:
   get MarketplaceId's
     for every marketplaceId:
       call real time availability`

At the end of batch execution I need to provide a nice summary in a file that shows,

- Number of accounts processed
- Number of marketplaceIds for each accoutId
- Number of marketplaceIds that failed to get real time availability
- Time took for processing one accountId

Question

1. Where do I persist those intermediate results ie. the different count on each iteration
2. How would I get those counts to the next step which is just a summary file writer

Would be really great if you provide any directions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write a tasklet to prepare a nice summery and put that tasklet as last step in the Job

```
     <step id="summeryFile" >
        <tasklet ref="summaryFilePreparationTasklet"/>
    </step>
```

and Bean Configuration is

```
<bean id="summaryFilePreparationTasklet" class="com.baji.batch.SummaryPreparationFile">
```

and Class file is

```
 package com.baji.batch;

    import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
    import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;

    /**
     * @Author
     * Bhaji Shaik
     * May 30, 2015
     */
    public class SummaryPreparationFile implements Tasklet {

        @Autowired
private Holder holder;
        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                    holder.getResults1();       
            //Write your own code to Prepare a neat summary preparation File
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Holder Class is

```
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class Holder {
        private List<Integer> results1;
        private List<Integer> results2;

         //Setter and getter methods
    }
```

Comment: I edited my qn to add some info. My question is, how to persist those counts since it is something I get during each iteration in the itemprocessor. Ex: real time availability for a marketplaceId

Comment: I have updated the answer. Holder Class is asingle ton class which we can autowire in any spring bean. it holds the results untill the job is completed.and  configure jobListener to reset the values in the holder bean before starting job by using @BeforeJob.